# Kerras : Found 39 images belonging to 3 classes. Found 49 images belonging to 3 classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

WIDTH = 299
HEIGHT = 299
BATCH_SIZE = 32

# data prep
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DIR,
    target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

For this part of the code my output is supposed to be"Found 39 images belonging to 2 classes.

Found 49 images belonging to 2 classes". But am getting 3 classes.

Please do help me.Thanks in advance.Also could anyone tell on what basis it divides into classes

for full code please do check out this link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18AN2AUM5sEsTMGUzFUL0FLSULtXF4Ps0

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Keras. It's the preprocessing steps from your Colab notebook. For some reason, there are 3 folders in your training directory. I ran your code without problems. Did you tamper with the folders?

Comment: @NicolasGervais this is how my training directorie is declared" TRAIN_DIR = '/content/drive/My Drive/train' "and there are only two subfolders inside training drectorie Cat and Dog.No folders hampered

Comment: To remove the created folder by Colab
!rmdir  Path_of_Folder/.ipynb_checkpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a new folder. It might be created by colab.

Answer (score 4):

Colab automatically creates a folder named '.ipynb_checkpoints' on the working directory in gdrive.
Make sure to delete it before you start generating your data.

Comment: This should be the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the directories present in your folder using this code, this displays the names of all directories in that folder. This code displays all directories even though it is hidden.

```
          import os
          dir = os.listdir('path_to_your_main_directory')
          print(dir)
```

Now, after you know the name of the unwanted subdirectory, delete it by using the below code

```
         file_path = ('path_to_your_main_directory/subdirectory_name')
         os.rmdir(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have binary classification problem, Can you try to change `class_mode` to 'binary` as shown below

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DIR,
    target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='binary')
```

#### Edit: I think it will add an extra file in the folder as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: changed to binary still getting the same output

Comment: I had similar experience. Please check the folder structure. There will be a .DS_Store file created by google drive when you upload a folder to gdrive. I am sure this is the reason as your colab works without any issue without modifying your code.

Comment: yeah you were right a new folder ".ipynb_checkpoints" was created by colab.Its working now.Thank you